# Why can't I make this function inline?

Tags: objective-c, c, function, inline

If I make this function inline and call it from a objective-c method, it gives me a `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

```
Vector addv(Vector v1, Vector v2) {// works
    return (Vector){v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y, v1.z + v2.z};
}

inline Vector addv(Vector v1, Vector v2) {// if I call this, does not build
    return (Vector){v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y, v1.z + v2.z};
}
```

Why is it doing this, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Maybe you need to declare it `static inline` or put it inside a header file.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: it already is inside a header file. what would making it static do?

Comment: If it is not `static` the code of that function is still emitted in every object file, so that function appears multiply-defined to the linker.

Answer (score 3):

C99 `inline` doesn't guarantee that a linker symbol is emitted. You'd have to place an "instantiation" in just one compilation unit (that is a .c).

So the `inline` definition in the .h file:

```
inline Vector addv(Vector v1, Vector v2) {// if I call this, does not build
    return (Vector){v1.x + v2.x, v1.y + v2.y, v1.z + v2.z};
}
```

and

```
Vector addv(Vector v1, Vector v2);
```

in one .c file to generate the symbol.